# tabular - how to set column separator

Tags: tables, line-spacing, column-width

Two questions about my table (MWE below). How do I make the widths of the column 'A' and 'B' the same? And how do I create some space between the `\cline` and the column names 'A' and 'B' so that 'True' in the first column remains vertically centered?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{True}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Something} \\
\cline{2-3}
&$A$ & $B$\\
\hline
C & 0 & 1 \\
D & 2 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

- You should avoid vertical rules as much as possible
- To get equal column widths, it is possible to use `tabularx` with column type `X`, but if you do not want to use `tabularx` then you must measure the width of "Something" and split the width between the two columns
- To add space below a ruler, use `\addlinespace`

Check this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\widthWidest}

\begin{document}
    
    \setlength{\widthWidest}{\widthof{Something}}
    \setlength{\widthWidest}{0.5\widthWidest}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c m[c]{\widthWidest} m[c]{\widthWidest}}
        
        \toprule
        
        & \Block[c]{1-2}{Something}  &
        \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        \addlinespace
        
        True & $A$ & $B$
        \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
        
        C & 0 & 1
        \\
        
        D & 2 & 0 
        \\
        
        \bottomrule
        
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I first show two versions of the table: left is your code, right a more elegant setup.

The vertical rules and the shift of “True” make the reading awkward: “True” is a header at the same conceptual level as “Something”, so they should stay at the same physical level.

[image]

On the other hand, your code better shows the issue: when TeX merges two (or more) cells and the total width of the merged cells is larger than the natural width of the spanned columns, the excess width goes entirely in the last spanned column.

In such a case you need some manual intervention and to measure the large spanning object.

We need to make the width of column A plus the width of column B (which we'll set equal) plus four times `\tabcolsep` the same as (or a bit wider than) the width of ”Something” plus twice `\tabcolsep`.

We can use `array` and its `w` column type for “fixed width columns”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\newlength{\eqcolwd}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% the columns A and B should be as wide as “Something” minus twice \tabcolsep
\settowidth{\eqcolwd}{Something}
\addtolength{\eqcolwd}{-2\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\eqcolwd}{0.5\eqcolwd}

\begin{tabular}{c w{c}{\eqcolwd} w{c}{\eqcolwd}}
\toprule
True & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Something} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
&$A$ & $B$\\
\midrule
C & 0 & 1 \\
D & 2 & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Some table}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist with your layout…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}

\newlength{\eqcolwd}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% the columns A and B should be as wide as “Something” minus twice \tabcolsep
\settowidth{\eqcolwd}{Something}
\addtolength{\eqcolwd}{-2\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\eqcolwd}{0.5\eqcolwd}

\begin{tabular}{c | w{c}{\eqcolwd} w{c}{\eqcolwd}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{True} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Something} \\
\cline{2-3}
&$A$ & $B$\\
\hline
C & 0 & 1 \\
D & 2 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Some table}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]